# Getting top 20 rows and the rest in 21st row in an SSRS Matrix Report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I want top 20 rows from an SSRS Matrix report and rest of the rows should be aggregated in 21st row with the row name hard coded as “Others”.

I have created the SSRS Matrix Report with row grouping based on  "Category_Name" and Column grouping based on  "Creation_Time". Column Group "Creation_Time" is formatted to show date in "M/yyyy" format. I am aggregating the “Id_Number” as Count(Id_Number) for each grouping and I want top 20 records sorted by count(Id_Number) in highest to the lowest order or descending order.

I have set the visibility condition as showed in the image:

[image]

I have given the following expression for the row "Others"

```
=count(iif(RunningValue(Fields!Category_Name.Value,countdistinct,nothing)>20,Fields!Id_Number.Value,0)
```

But it didn't work. I got the error saying "Running functions cannot be specified as nested aggregates".

I have earlier tried using TOP N filter on SSRS Row grouping based on count(Id_Number) which gives Top 20 rows.But if we add the " group total" to the row grouping, it will give the total of all rows and not just the top 20 rows. The logic that I thought of was to subtract the total of top 20 rows from the total of all rows. But I am not able to get the total of top 20 rows.

I used basic sql query with 2 parameters, @Begin AND @End :

```
 SELECT Category_Name, Id_Number, Creation_Date
 FROM   Tbl
 WHERE  Creation_Date BETWEEN  @Begin AND @End
```

The desired output of this report is this:

[image]

I am getting everything as per the desired output except for the last row "Others".

Comment: Are you getting your data from an SQL query?

Comment: Yes, Getting the data from mssql query.

Comment: You will want to handle this in your SQL instead of your report, using `row_number` and a wrapping `select`.  Are you able to post your script?

Answer (score 0):

Amend your sql select script to include the following:
CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(Id_Number)DESC) >20 then 'Top 20' else 'Others' End AS 'Type'

Then in your report add in another separate tablix that is filtered by "type" = "others"